# How can I use redis or firebase or any local database for chat application with socket.io and backend as node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, redis

How can I use Redis or firebase or any local database for chat applications with socket.io and backend as node.js?
I have build a chat application with socket io and react and node.js but I want to store chats in local storage just like room database in android.

Comment: do you want to the syntazx of using redis ????

Comment: I want to know where it is used? Is it good fit for my application.?

Comment: I can give more explanation if you find difficulty in understanding my question.

Comment: if your data is user data, then set to firebase. If your data is global then set it to redis.

Comment: I am using it for chat application so I have to use firebase?
May I know how to go about it? I am completely new to firebase.
how can i use it with react.js and socket.io

Comment: I would assume there are guides online on firebase. You should really check at least one instead of trying to get someone to tell you the same info here.

Comment: I have checked many guides. I did not find anything with chat application + firebase + socket.io.

Comment: Recommending a technology is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You'll have to research the technologies you're considering and make up your own mind. This would be a good place to get started: https://www.google.com/search?q=chat+application+%2B+firebase+%2B+socket.io

Comment: Firebase uses its own js SDK to do the communication via websockets, things like cache and sync later when the connection is poor. To read the data written on firebase you can use cloud functions (similar to lamda functions) or offical mom package to connect from node server to firebase. The SDK won't allow you to store data locally only. You may have to use some encryption if you wish to keep data private.